# Print a new array, where all elements will be greater/less than a specific number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I changed my question using code, which I take from comment bellow.I added 2 conditions and have another one problem, I think the problem is in indents!Please check and say me if you see in my code mistake !

```
function filterNums (array, num, condition) {

var outputarray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 1) {
  if (condition == "greater"){
    if (array[i] > num) {
      outputarray.push(array[i]); // put the array number in to the output array
    }
  } else if (condition == "less") {
    if (array[i] < num) {
      outputarray.push(array[i]); // put the array number in to the output array
    }
}   else if (condition!=='undefined'){
    if (array[i] > num){
        outputarray.push(array[i])
    }
    }   else if (num!=='undefined' && condition!=='undefined')
            if (array[i] > 0){
                outputarray.push(array[i])
    }

  
}

return outputarray;
```

}

console.log(filterNums([-3, 3, 4, 0, 44, -11, 5]));

The result of output must be : [ 3, 4, 44, 5 ]
But I got []. What is the problem in my code?
So in input data we don't have num and condition, just array.It must return all positive numbers from array.

Comment: Have you tried using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)? Give it a go, include what you've tried here, then we have something to help you with.

Comment: Think about it ... if there is a native `filter` method already in place why not just express and provide the condition as function in order to get directly passed to this very method ... thus ...
`filterNums([-1, 2, 4, 0, 55, -12, 3], 11, 'greater');` then turns into ...
`[-1, 2, 4, 0, 55, -12, 3].filter(num => num > 11);` ... which is more readable and even shorter. There is no need to implement additional code which has to determine cases like `'greater'` and `'less'` and another day even `'greaterThanOrEqualTo'`, etc  ... just change the callback accordingly `num => num >= 11`.

Comment: @РудневськаЛюбов ... `"I wrote a function called filterNums"` ... But the code is actually missing. Thus nobody can tell or hint where you got stuck. Providing the code that one claims to have actually written therefore is also appreciated very much.

Comment: @РудневськаЛюбов ... The code you just took from one of the answers is the worst of the possible picks. Maybe you try to develop first an understanding of both your actual problem and how you would tackle/solve it in terms of short instructions. And since you mention ... `"I added 2 conditions and have another one problem, I think the problem is in indents!"` ... what is your level of experience in JavaScript at all ..? And this last Q. is in order to understand which level of support you are in need of.

Comment: It is my first task on Java Script!Very low level!But I need to do this task.Using different input data)

Comment: @РудневськаЛюбов ... And you really need to write your own filter function instead of going with the most easy forms of the presented use cases like ... `[ /*...*/ ].filter(num => num > 55);` ... `[ /*...*/ ].filter(num => num < 6);` ... `[ /*...*/ ].filter(num => num < -33);` ..? And in case of having to implement your own solution what should it be based on? Simple for loops, more advanced array methods except for `filter`, or are you even allowed to make use of `filter` itself?

Comment: @РудневськаЛюбов ... if there are no open questions you might consider accepting the answer which was most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this by using the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) built-in function:

```js
const filterNums = (arr, val, condition) =>
  arr.filter(item => (condition === 'greater' ? item > val : item < val));

console.log(filterNums([-1, 2, 4, 0, 55, -12, 3], 11, 'greater')); //[ 55]
console.log(filterNums([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], 6, 'less')); // [-2, 2, 3, 0, -13]
console.log(filterNums([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], -33, 'less')); //  []
```

Comment: Works !!! But have another one case with input data!!)

Answer (score 0):

I will write a simple Javascript basic code for this nice idea. You can use a *built-in function* like the previous answer (`filter`), but first try to make it without the help of *built-in functions* to gain more experience.

```js
/*
 filterNums([-1, 2, 4, 0, 55, -12, 3], 11, 'greater');  //[ 55]
filterNums([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], 6, 'less'); // [-2, 2, 3, 0, -13]
filterNums([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], -33, 'less'); //  []*/

function filterNums (array, num, condition) {

  var outputarray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 1) {
  
    if (num != undefined) {
  
      if (condition == undefined || condition == "greater") {
        if (array[i] > num) {
          outputarray.push(array[i]); // put the array number in to the output array
        }
      } else if (condition == "less") {
        if (array[i] < num) {
          outputarray.push(array[i]); // put the array number in to the output array
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (array[i] > 0) {
        outputarray.push(array[i]); // put the positive array number in to the output array
      }
    }
  }
  
  return outputarray;
}

console.log(filterNums([-1, 2, 4, 0, 55, -12, 3], 11, 'greater'))
console.log(filterNums([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], 6, 'less'))
console.log(filterNums([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], -33, 'less'))

// New Edit
console.log(filterNums([-3, 3, 4, 0, 44, -11, 5]));

// New Edit
console.log(filterNums([-3, 3, 4, 0, 44, -11, 5], 9));
```

If you have any question, please comment.

Comment: You are welcome, If you have any new question just ask it.

Comment: I changed my code using your examples!!Thanks a lot!But have another one mistake!If you have time, please help!!!

Comment: You are welcome, just give me 1 min to check it

Comment: please can you check the code now, I edit it `console.log(filterNums([-3, 3, 4, 0, 44, -11, 5]));` it now gives `[ 3, 4, 44, 5 ]`. If you have any question just comment

Comment: I have one case: console.log(filterNums([-3, 3, 4, 0, 44, -11, 5], 9)); It must return 44.It is when we have a number 9. But it is not work.When we run this new code. Thats why I wrote this: else if (condition!=='undefined'){
    if (array[i] > num){
        outputarray.push(array[i])
    }

Comment: `console.log(filterNums([-3, 3, 4, 0, 44, -11, 5], 9));` for this you should specify the condition `greate or less`, I wiil put the `greater` to be default, even if the user didn't wrote it. Just one minute

Comment: I edit the code `console.log(filterNums([-3, 3, 4, 0, 44, -11, 5], 9));` it now returns `44`, Check the code, If you any question just comment

Comment: @Рудневська Любов, If you have any question just comment, your idea is nice and you can let it more pretty

Comment: I will tell you a very nice idea to add it to it, `console.log(filterNums([-3, 3, 9, 0, 44, -11, 5], 9, 'checkifexist'));` it will return `number 9 exists in the array`, do you want to make it?

Comment: @Рудневська Любов hello friend, do you wan't to continue the idea?

Answer (score 0):

Everything that had to be said can be found in the comments which discuss the OP's approach. Therefore an implementation is the only thing left which still could be provided ...

```js
// quote from the OP's first provided question / version ...
// "by default, the number is 0, and the last parameter is 'greater'"

function filterNumberValues(arr, val, condition) {

  // be failsave, sanitize the number value.
  val = Number(val);
  val = Number.isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;

  const lookupTable = {

    // discouraged non standard usage
    'GREATER': num => num > val,
    'LOWER': num => num < val,
    'LESS': num => num < val,

    // encouraged standard usage
    'GTE': num => num >= val,
    'GT': num => num > val,
    'EQ': num => num === val,
    'LT': num => num < val,
    'LTE' : num => num <= val,
  }
  // be failsave, sanitize and transform the filter condition.
  condition = String(condition).toUpperCase();
  condition = lookupTable[condition] || lookupTable['GT'];

  // use an array's native `filter` method.
  return arr.filter(condition);
}

console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-1, 2, 4, 0, 55, -12, 3], 4, 'greater')
); // [ 55 ]
console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-1, 2, 4, 0, 55, -12, 3], 4, 'gt')
); // [ 55]
console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-1, 2, 4, 0, 55, -12, 3], 4, 'gte')
); // [ 4, 55]
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], 2, 'less')
); // [-2, 0, -13]
console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], 2, 'lt')
); // [-2, 0, -13]
console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], 2, 'lte')
); // [-2, 2, 0, -13]
console.log('\n');


console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], -13, 'lt')
); //  []
console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], -13, 'lte')
); //  [-13]
console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], -13, 'eq')
); //  [-13]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

In case of not being allowed to utilize the native `filter` method one could implement an own process via e.g. a `while` loop ...

```js
// quote from the OP's first provided question / version ...
// "by default, the number is 0, and the last parameter is 'greater'"

function filterNumberValues(arr, val, condition) {

  // sanitize all arguments.
  arr = Array.isArray(arr) && arr || [];

  val = Number(val);
  val = Number.isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;

  condition = String(condition).toUpperCase();
  condition = (
    (condition === 'GREATER') ||
    (condition === 'LESS')
  ) && condition || 'GREATER';

  // pepare filter process.
  const result = [];
  let number;

  const len = arr.length;
  let idx = -1;

  // do filter.
  while (++idx < len) {
    if (idx in arr) { // skip "holes" in array.

      number = arr[idx];
      if (
        (condition === 'GREATER') 
        ? (number > val)
        : (number < val)
      ) {
        result.push(number);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-1, 2, 4, 0, 55, -12, 3], 4, 'greater')
); // [ 55 ]
console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-1, 2, 4, 0, 55, -12, 3], 54, 'GREATER')
); // [ 55]
console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-1, 2, 4, 0, 55, -12, 3], 55, 'greater')
); // []
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], 2, 'less')
); // [-2, 0, -13]
console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], 0, 'LESS')
); // [-2, -13]
console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], -2, 'LESS')
); // [-13]
console.log(
  filterNumberValues([-2, 2, 3, 0, 43, -13, 6], -13, 'less')
); // []
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @РудневськаЛюбов ... are there any questions left? It is also considered good style if the OP accepts the most useful answer.